# How to display selectable variations without attributes?

Tags: commerce

With Drupal Commerce 2, each of my products have multiple variations which are unique and can be adequately described by their variation title.

I can not figure out how to display a dropdown for the add to cart form based the variation title alone. All that is shown is the title of first variation, the price and the add to cart button. No dropdown with the other variations.

The only way I can get it to work is by first creating a series of matching attributes which is both a repetitive exercise and seems like it should not be necessary.

What am I missing?

Similar question: [What's the best the approach to add an extra attribute field in Drupal Commerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35177434/55075)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you question correctly, you accomplish this by going to your order item type, choose manager form display then you have the field available called Purchased entity ... you want to change the default widget from product variation attributes to Product variation title.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I eventually figured this out for myself but find that when such an item is added to the cart, only the variation title is shown. I would have expected the order item to be titled 'Product Title - Variation Title'

Comment: It turns out this is not possible in Drupal Commerce with modifications of cart, checkout and order views. Now submitted as a feature request. https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2923799